# Suspicious Commands in Shell History

Tags: linux, shell, security, centos, root

I am working as root on a remote virtual server running CentOS (SELinux enabled). No one else should know my login credentials. However I noticed the following sequence of commands in my shell history:

```
mount
top
mount
less /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf
ll /usr/bin/fail2ban-client 
less /var/log/messages
crontab -e
ip a
less /var/log/messages-20141228
less /var/log/messages-20150105
less /proc/sys/kernel/softlockup_panic 
cd /proc/sys/kernel/
grep softlockup *
ll
grep time *
grep 10 *
grep intel_idle.max_cstate *
grep max_cstate *
cd ..
ll
vim /etc/sysctl.conf 
vim /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf 
less /etc/sysconfig/grub 
cat /proc/cmdline
```

Is this caused by some kind of cron-process or similiar? Or should I be worried about some intruder?

Comment: If it's not you, it's not cron. If you are the only one user, then you have a new room-mate.

Comment: I'd be worried.  Your shell history only contains commands that are run from an interactive command shell.

Comment: @StephenC but what was my assumed visitor doing there then?

Comment: @StephenC `/etc/sysctl.conf` etc. are *apparently* untouched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be worried. Your shell history only contains commands that are run from an interactive command shell.

So this appears to be evidence that someone else was logged in.

> but what was my assumed visitor doing there then?

Well most of what he is doing is looking at things.  It looks like an admin checking for evidence of problems.

Check to see if the "/etc/sysctl" files were actually edited.

The concerning thing is that you have an unexpected visitor at all.  But it is possible that is an admin from the service provider.  It is quite conceivable that they legitimately have root access to the virtual via a different account to the one that you used.

It is also possible that you are dealing with someone / something more sophisticated ... and this is a false trail designed to put you off the scent of what he / she / it was really doing.

I'd ask the service provider (the folks who administer the virtualization, etc) if their admins can get into your VM, and if this was them.  After all, you haven't any evidence (in this history) of someone changing things or looking to access private information on the virtual.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I have mailed the provider. I was wondering whether VMwareTools could be responsible.

Comment: Still waiting for a response from the provider … :(

Comment: The provider informed me they checked the server because of a former kernel panic. I’m relieved.

Comment: Good.  However, it was good to check.  And you know know that next time you see something unexpected in the history that it *could* be your provider.